# Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) installation on Unix - garbled character in GUI over xMing

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, installation, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am installing weblogic 12c (12.1.3) on RHEL (Red hat enterprise Linux Server 7.1) using GUI Mode. I am using X11 forwarding using XMing and connecting to the server over SSH using Putty. 
When I run the command "java -jar Weblogic/fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar" it shows some initial error as "Checking monitor: Must be configured to display 256 bit color" Failed. I ignored the installation and went ahead.
But when the GUI opened the characters are scrambled and unreadable as the image attached next
[Weblogic GUI - Not readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0utH.png)
I tried installation using both JDK 1.7 and 1.8 and had the similar results
I seems to be issue with some character encoding but was not able to figure out. I checked the Unix $LANG environment variable and it is set properly to "en_US.UTF-8" I checked Putty if there is any option related to encoding. And found one under Window > Translation > Remote Character Set and the value is set as UTF-8

I checked by copying text inside the text box beside the Browse equivalent one, and pasted it in notepad. The text is valid in notepad

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue with the help of the Unix team. 
I checked for other GUI installer like IBM Unica Campaign. I got the similar issue. So I was sure it has nothing to do with the installer. Either something with the SSH pipe or something in the server. I shared the details of one server where it worked fine earlier and asked Unix team to compare the packages.
Unix Admin team found that the issue might be due to the font  lyx-fonts which didn't exist in the server where it was working fine. The font was removed by Unix admin team. After that the installer was showing correct string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However, if you install all prerequisite packages (see the requirements guide of Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c) for Linux then the problem disappears. Specifically you must install redhat-lsb-4.1-27.0.1.el7 for x86_64 (Redhat or OEL 7). This installs the lyx-fonts again, but also some stuff that makes your X-Windows display ok again.

Answer (score 0):

Also I had the same issue. I solved it. I just install the package "xorg-x11-fonts-Type1"